# How to get the Value of an Checkbox by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some checkboxes with a class attribute and now i try to get the value if they get clicked. For some reason it does not work:

Javascript:

```
(".myClass").click (function(){
            boxArr.push($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

HTML:

```
<td>
  <form action="">
    <div class="myClass">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="box'+index+'" id="MyBox'+pageForBoxes+''+index+'" value="'+daten.identification+'" > Anzeigen
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</td>
```

Comment: need to share your html also

Comment: `(".myClass")` should be `$(".myClass")`

Comment: erm jeah sure my HTML `<td><form action=""><div class="myClass"><label><input type="checkbox" name="box'+index+'" id="MyBox'+pageForBoxes+''+index+'" value="'+daten.identification+'" > Anzeigen</label></div></form></td></tr>'); ` hope you can read it first time I use stack overflow sorry for these are my checkboxes they are in an each loop so its more than 1 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
var boxArr = [];
$(".myClass").click(function() {//missing $ here
  boxArr.push($(this).find('input').val());//the input is a descendant of the div so
  snippet.log(boxArr.join())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>


<form action="">
    <div class="myClass">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="box1" id="MyBox1" value="1" />Anzeigen</label>
    </div>
</form>
<form action="">
    <div class="myClass">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="box2" id="MyBox2" value="2" />Anzeigen</label>
    </div>
</form>
<form action="">
    <div class="myClass">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="box3" id="MyBox3" value="3" />Anzeigen</label>
    </div>
</form>
<form action="">
    <div class="myClass">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="box4" id="MyBox4" value="4" />Anzeigen</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `val()`:

```
(".myClass").click (function(){
            boxArr.push($(this).val());
```

Comment: Thanks so I don't get errors :D but the my variable just has empty strings now